# Xcode link error "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm facing next error after updating to the latests versions of the pods I'm using:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Flurry", referenced from:
  objc-class-ref in AnalyticsKitFlurryProvider.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

I've been trying several ideas after googling:

- Delete pods and workspace and regenerate
- Upgrade/downgrade Cocoapods
- Change target settings to: "Build Active Architecture Only = Yes"; "Valid Architectures = arm64, armv7, armv7s, i386"

None of them works.

I think this issue is related to mixing swift and objective c pods.

Here is my Podfile:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://pventura1976.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/Specs'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'kPlant' do

pod 'pventuraLib'
pod 'iPlantLib'
pod 'AnalyticsKit/Flurry'
pod 'FLEX'
pod 'PBFlatUI'
pod 'MSDynamicsDrawerViewController'
pod 'LAWalkthrough', :git => 'https://github.com/pventura1976/LAWalkthrough'
pod 'RPFloatingPlaceholders'
pod 'iCarousel'
pod 'FXImageView'
pod 'BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets', :git => 'https://github.com/pventura1976/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets', :commit => 'ccbfd6464691863bc594fe235906202c751ed39f'
pod 'MTMigration'
pod 'VTAcknowledgementsViewController'
pod 'RMDateSelectionViewController'
pod 'RMPickerViewController'
pod 'AAShareBubbles'
pod 'TapkuLibrary'
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'TSAssetsPickerController'
pod 'MWPhotoBrowser', :git => 'https://github.com/SmileBack/MWPhotoBrowser'
pod 'BSKeyboardControls'
pod 'InstagramKit'
pod 'PEPhotoCropEditor'
pod 'CRToast'
pod 'BFNavigationBarDrawer'
pod 'Nimbus'
pod 'pop'
pod 'LBBlurredImage'
pod 'ASValueTrackingSlider'
pod 'M13BadgeView'
pod 'KGModal', :git => 'https://github.com/pventura1976/KGModal', :commit => '72b40d400d8acbdc9abc1a07aeedf6304db6b173'
pod 'SSKeychain'
pod 'PNChart'
pod 'JBChartView'
pod 'Ensembles'
pod 'Ensembles/Dropbox'
pod 'Dropbox-iOS-SDK'
pod 'DZNEmptyDataSet', :git => 'https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet', :commit => '526b54ca6c15e6a3cee3e92cea5c43e13a59f968'
pod 'M13ContextMenu'
pod 'WCFastCell'
pod 'SWTableViewCell'
pod 'UIScrollSlidingPages', :git => 'https://github.com/iEdward/UIScrollSlidingPages'
pod 'UIImage-ResizeMagick'
pod 'SVPullToRefresh'
pod 'ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer'
pod 'MagicalRecord'
pod 'SVProgressHUD'
pod 'PAPreferences'
pod 'ReactiveCocoa'
pod 'Mantle'
pod 'INTULocationManager'
pod 'RateLimit'
pod 'SDiPhoneVersion'
pod 'ContextMenu.iOS', :git => 'https://github.com/pventura1976/Context-Menu.iOS'

end

target 'kPlantTests' do

end
```

It includes two private pods (iPlantLib and pventuraLib).

Here is the Podfile.lock:

```
PODS:
  - AAShareBubbles (1.1.0)
  - AFNetworking (2.6.0):
    - AFNetworking/NSURLConnection (= 2.6.0)
    - AFNetworking/NSURLSession (= 2.6.0)
    - AFNetworking/Reachability (= 2.6.0)
    - AFNetworking/Security (= 2.6.0)
    - AFNetworking/Serialization (= 2.6.0)
    - AFNetworking/UIKit (= 2.6.0)
  - AFNetworking/NSURLConnection (2.6.0):
    - AFNetworking/Reachability
    - AFNetworking/Security
    - AFNetworking/Serialization
  - AFNetworking/NSURLSession (2.6.0):
    - AFNetworking/Reachability
    - AFNetworking/Security
    - AFNetworking/Serialization
  - AFNetworking/Reachability (2.6.0)
  - AFNetworking/Security (2.6.0)
  - AFNetworking/Serialization (2.6.0)
  - AFNetworking/UIKit (2.6.0):
    - AFNetworking/NSURLConnection
    - AFNetworking/NSURLSession
  - AnalyticsKit/Core (1.2.7)
  - AnalyticsKit/Flurry (1.2.7):
    - AnalyticsKit/Core
    - FlurrySDK
  - ASValueTrackingSlider (0.11.2)
  - BFNavigationBarDrawer (1.0.2)
  - BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets (1.0.6):
    - BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets/TableAlertView (= 1.0.6)
  - BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets/TableAlertView (1.0.6)
  - Box (1.2.2)
  - BSKeyboardControls (2.2)
  - CMPopTipView (2.2.0)
  - ContextMenu.iOS (1.0.0)
  - CRToast (0.0.8)
  - DACircularProgress (2.3.1)
  - Dropbox-iOS-SDK (1.3.13)
  - DZNEmptyDataSet (1.5.2)
  - Ensembles (1.4.1):
    - Ensembles/Core (= 1.4.1)
  - Ensembles/Core (1.4.1)
  - Ensembles/Dropbox (1.4.1):
    - Dropbox-iOS-SDK
    - Dropbox-OSX-SDK
    - Ensembles/Core
  - FLEX (2.0.6)
  - FlurrySDK (6.7.0):
    - FlurrySDK/FlurrySDK (= 6.7.0)
  - FlurrySDK/FlurrySDK (6.7.0)
  - FXImageView (1.3.5)
  - iCarousel (1.8.2)
  - InstagramKit (3.6.8):
    - AFNetworking (~> 2.0)
    - InstagramKit/Exclude-UICKeyChainStore (= 3.6.8)
  - InstagramKit/Exclude-UICKeyChainStore (3.6.8):
    - AFNetworking (~> 2.0)
  - INTULocationManager (4.0.0)
  - iPlantLib (0.0.9):
    - INTULocationManager
    - MagicalRecord
    - Mantle
    - PAPreferences
    - pventuraLib
    - ReactiveCocoa
  - ISO8601DateFormatter (0.7)
  - ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer (0.7.0):
    - ISO8601DateFormatter (~> 0.7)
    - RKValueTransformers (~> 1.1.0)
  - JBChartView (2.8.15)
  - KGModal (1.1.1-Cabo)
  - LAWalkthrough (1.0.0)
  - LBBlurredImage (0.2.2)
  - M13BadgeView (1.0.4)
  - M13ContextMenu (1.0.3)
  - MagicalRecord (2.3.0)
  - Mantle (2.0.5):
    - Mantle/extobjc (= 2.0.5)
  - Mantle/extobjc (2.0.5)
  - MBProgressHUD (0.9.1)
  - MSDynamicsDrawerViewController (1.5.1)
  - MTMigration (0.0.5)
  - MWPhotoBrowser (1.4.0):
    - DACircularProgress
    - MBProgressHUD (~> 0.8)
    - PSTCollectionView (~> 1.2)
    - SDWebImage (~> 3.5.4)
  - Nimbus (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/AttributedLabel (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Badge (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Collections (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Collections (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Core (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/CSS (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Interapp (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Launcher (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Models (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/NetworkControllers (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/NetworkImage (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Overview (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/PagingScrollView (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Photos (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/Textfield (= 1.2.0)
    - Nimbus/WebController (= 1.2.0)
  - Nimbus/AttributedLabel (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
  - Nimbus/Badge (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
  - Nimbus/Collections (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
  - Nimbus/Core (1.2.0)
  - Nimbus/CSS (1.2.0):
    - AFNetworking (~> 2.1)
    - Nimbus/Core
    - Nimbus/Textfield
  - Nimbus/Interapp (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
  - Nimbus/Launcher (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
    - Nimbus/PagingScrollView
  - Nimbus/Models (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
  - Nimbus/NetworkControllers (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
  - Nimbus/NetworkImage (1.2.0):
    - AFNetworking (~> 2.1)
    - Nimbus/Core
  - Nimbus/Overview (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
    - Nimbus/Models
  - Nimbus/PagingScrollView (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
  - Nimbus/Photos (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
    - Nimbus/PagingScrollView
  - Nimbus/Textfield (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
  - Nimbus/WebController (1.2.0):
    - Nimbus/Core
  - PAPreferences (0.5)
  - PBFlatUI (1.1.0)
  - PEPhotoCropEditor (1.3.1)
  - PNChart (0.8.7):
    - UICountingLabel (~> 1.2.0)
  - pop (1.0.8)
  - PSTCollectionView (1.2.3)
  - pventuraLib (0.0.12):
    - AnalyticsKit/Flurry
    - CMPopTipView
    - ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer
    - SVProgressHUD
  - RateLimit (1.2.0)
  - ReactiveCocoa (3.0.0):
    - ReactiveCocoa/UI (= 3.0.0)
    - Result (~> 0.4.1)
  - ReactiveCocoa/Core (3.0.0):
    - ReactiveCocoa/no-arc
    - Result (~> 0.4.1)
  - ReactiveCocoa/no-arc (3.0.0):
    - Result (~> 0.4.1)
  - ReactiveCocoa/UI (3.0.0):
    - ReactiveCocoa/Core
    - Result (~> 0.4.1)
  - Result (0.4.4):
    - Box (~> 1.2)
  - RKValueTransformers (1.1.2)
  - RMActionController (1.0.4)
  - RMDateSelectionViewController (2.0.1):
    - RMActionController (~> 1.0.0)
  - RMPickerViewController (2.0.1):
    - RMActionController (~> 1.0.0)
  - RPFloatingPlaceholders (0.3.2)
  - SDiPhoneVersion (1.1.2)
  - SDWebImage (3.5.4):
    - SDWebImage/Core (= 3.5.4)
  - SDWebImage/Core (3.5.4)
  - SSKeychain (1.2.3)
  - SVProgressHUD (1.1.3)
  - SVPullToRefresh (0.4.1)
  - SWTableViewCell (0.3.7)
  - TapkuLibrary (0.3.8)
  - TSAssetsPickerController (1.2)
  - UICountingLabel (1.2.0)
  - UIImage-ResizeMagick (0.0.1)
  - UIScrollSlidingPages (1.3.1)
  - VTAcknowledgementsViewController (0.15)
  - WCFastCell (1.1)

DEPENDENCIES:
  - AAShareBubbles
  - AFNetworking
  - AnalyticsKit/Flurry
  - ASValueTrackingSlider
  - BFNavigationBarDrawer
  - BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets (from `https://github.com/pventura1976/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets`,
    commit `ccbfd6464691863bc594fe235906202c751ed39f`)
  - BSKeyboardControls
  - ContextMenu.iOS (from `https://github.com/pventura1976/Context-Menu.iOS`)
  - CRToast
  - Dropbox-iOS-SDK
  - DZNEmptyDataSet (from `https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet`, commit `526b54ca6c15e6a3cee3e92cea5c43e13a59f968`)
  - Ensembles
  - Ensembles/Dropbox
  - FLEX
  - FXImageView
  - iCarousel
  - InstagramKit
  - INTULocationManager
  - iPlantLib
  - ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer
  - JBChartView
  - KGModal (from `https://github.com/pventura1976/KGModal`, commit `72b40d400d8acbdc9abc1a07aeedf6304db6b173`)
  - LAWalkthrough (from `https://github.com/pventura1976/LAWalkthrough`)
  - LBBlurredImage
  - M13BadgeView
  - M13ContextMenu
  - MagicalRecord
  - Mantle
  - MSDynamicsDrawerViewController
  - MTMigration
  - MWPhotoBrowser (from `https://github.com/SmileBack/MWPhotoBrowser`)
  - Nimbus
  - PAPreferences
  - PBFlatUI
  - PEPhotoCropEditor
  - PNChart
  - pop
  - pventuraLib
  - RateLimit
  - ReactiveCocoa
  - RMDateSelectionViewController
  - RMPickerViewController
  - RPFloatingPlaceholders
  - SDiPhoneVersion
  - SSKeychain
  - SVProgressHUD
  - SVPullToRefresh
  - SWTableViewCell
  - TapkuLibrary
  - TSAssetsPickerController
  - UIImage-ResizeMagick
  - UIScrollSlidingPages (from `https://github.com/iEdward/UIScrollSlidingPages`)
  - VTAcknowledgementsViewController
  - WCFastCell

EXTERNAL SOURCES:
  BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets:
    :commit: ccbfd6464691863bc594fe235906202c751ed39f
    :git: https://github.com/pventura1976/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets
  ContextMenu.iOS:
    :git: https://github.com/pventura1976/Context-Menu.iOS
  DZNEmptyDataSet:
    :commit: 526b54ca6c15e6a3cee3e92cea5c43e13a59f968
    :git: https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet
  KGModal:
    :commit: 72b40d400d8acbdc9abc1a07aeedf6304db6b173
    :git: https://github.com/pventura1976/KGModal
  LAWalkthrough:
    :git: https://github.com/pventura1976/LAWalkthrough
  MWPhotoBrowser:
    :git: https://github.com/SmileBack/MWPhotoBrowser
  UIScrollSlidingPages:
    :git: https://github.com/iEdward/UIScrollSlidingPages

CHECKOUT OPTIONS:
  BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets:
    :commit: ccbfd6464691863bc594fe235906202c751ed39f
    :git: https://github.com/pventura1976/BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets
  ContextMenu.iOS:
    :commit: 59db45dc57b8e884c2e6732a3c061e2a4bd8aa93
    :git: https://github.com/pventura1976/Context-Menu.iOS
  DZNEmptyDataSet:
    :commit: 526b54ca6c15e6a3cee3e92cea5c43e13a59f968
    :git: https://github.com/dzenbot/DZNEmptyDataSet
  KGModal:
    :commit: 72b40d400d8acbdc9abc1a07aeedf6304db6b173
    :git: https://github.com/pventura1976/KGModal
  LAWalkthrough:
    :commit: c41a503a91b999cb4098480b89981ba931007c69
    :git: https://github.com/pventura1976/LAWalkthrough
  MWPhotoBrowser:
    :commit: 990d22356ac01b1449d84590e39548b485dd7150
    :git: https://github.com/SmileBack/MWPhotoBrowser
  UIScrollSlidingPages:
    :commit: 1197f1d71357f21b7eca8a2627457a764e7f63a2
    :git: https://github.com/iEdward/UIScrollSlidingPages

SPEC CHECKSUMS:
  AAShareBubbles: 960610d6a3c4da57d7cd295f4bec68790307bce8
  AFNetworking: 79f7eb1a0fcfa7beb409332b2ca49afe9ce53b05
  AnalyticsKit: d5abc65807aaeb1842f0ce16b11f745d904b5b29
  ASValueTrackingSlider: 45c9f78252da60de01d8f2afe869aaf90dd978d9
  BFNavigationBarDrawer: 7114305b2eb64f796aeee63029a037e30bf37a93
  BlockAlertsAnd-ActionSheets: 15be37bd381afaae85c2d4229db102c2cac742fa
  Box: a92e8aa4c099e6bc0733829665caf9e668ef53b8
  BSKeyboardControls: b701935e789961102e3f20063bba7185800a2d3f
  CMPopTipView: a0a88404b9f46a5cfc16ce54bdb1b9bf9acb9aff
  ContextMenu.iOS: 7da78b3f99e604669b75e55146c6c33147f64f99
  CRToast: b087127369b4c603726ef6249d74d0d737629ab8
  DACircularProgress: 4dd437c0fc3da5161cb289e07ac449493d41db71
  Dropbox-iOS-SDK: e0c9b08d1604b39cb78c1d0333251de0f6bdec60
  DZNEmptyDataSet: 741da409081a4bf707c949c964623a6ad1799772
  Ensembles: 90013c435ff874a7a9ccb7a334b74b93ac53dc12
  FLEX: 3c390976e788d3d447b614ea1714ffc8fc914cf3
  FlurrySDK: ea03fd78ffb32886e26c9b7634ff0d8cb18dcd55
  FXImageView: 7d84722b37f0afea9a64f12fdd4a6c7f9ecc4b16
  iCarousel: 67c8a43da5a46795b56aadfc96cd36a16f6149b2
  InstagramKit: 2dc81dd8a9b534bbf918fbf8c4bc11eef11040a3
  INTULocationManager: 754f2800415378b7bb2c07be103449e1f6a2cc70
  iPlantLib: 1faaa266785a71a44b34a7716a1c1534d0d18467
  ISO8601DateFormatter: ab926648eebe497f4d167c0fd083992f959f1274
  ISO8601DateFormatterValueTransformer: f9ffeb6841f2a56d01b0a47b4cf1becf20954147
  JBChartView: d77d6a713a32547b24ccfaeba90958e7274f0c9d
  KGModal: 9ee82fda738880de3cad8ccec416f0195db7b098
  LAWalkthrough: e97a16a0384bde1e714b0ec4eeafe0c76270ef15
  LBBlurredImage: 700634c17922bc2d22343118e7deb6a3ca12db43
  M13BadgeView: 700dd0714fdc837c0cf1c8c004454963ec22441f
  M13ContextMenu: 49b6eb55e92b3adcdb2f8f5bdef876508cecb606
  MagicalRecord: 89eb7d7ead39fb37f01c3d010665ee94d17f8dba
  Mantle: 1912395033f601de5adc8ee91e48f46e4c7051ad
  MBProgressHUD: c47f2c166c126cf2ce36498d80f33e754d4e93ad
  MSDynamicsDrawerViewController: 2874df90f5e9453dc7d4e32f8038b50615d4baa7
  MTMigration: 725315e6469c8fd7d13966887f59e65eb8aecb2e
  MWPhotoBrowser: 02c13159c8cc89740a53a2e59b368593b2495715
  Nimbus: 3d6dfdeabf548ba4eb43be24e74fd202fb8c4e22
  PAPreferences: 9f0ffb1e67174a0df001af9d3320166ceb9ee6f5
  PBFlatUI: d797c6de1d28245287d695d74178dc75895d0bd9
  PEPhotoCropEditor: 613292fce009efd085e7aed975f1ebb3fec8bb7b
  PNChart: c1755716bbd45386d2035b2bf2ce73e6d3f8cb22
  pop: bb773ae2c791ca2629de13b347e7a8b450fa6a57
  PSTCollectionView: 6749df92885353521f55279a7ce2b293762e2be4
  pventuraLib: 63293b7c53a485469b73e657a6dd85c92732c7ca
  RateLimit: fd0afab3943f7b97b374d0a24b68dcc71daa4638
  ReactiveCocoa: 5c4710e2f00f69f39a7f135d1f3ab48f8dace034
  Result: b44f6bc8762bbffaf2c5df58f2c7d12c3496ced8
  RKValueTransformers: 66ac5e4f077fdbe3496e792d89eeff4c3eb67701
  RMActionController: 19423654600d40ca15132a4e548d005042d68f09
  RMDateSelectionViewController: 027bdeeaacb78b2b528808ed21efd697490d2b4e
  RMPickerViewController: b94b078e1ef531a0b9dbc2e0c3004f91de50d978
  RPFloatingPlaceholders: 4687b57f7965e6a2bacfc1642f7f2981491b146e
  SDiPhoneVersion: c52245ccaab8142701e2e7fb8f0391ba3f255b76
  SDWebImage: b7546bef8a1a7d7f4995b2e43f7644ac04ceb186
  SSKeychain: 3f42991739c6c60a9cf1bbd4dff6c0d3694bcf3d
  SVProgressHUD: 748080e4f36e603f6c02aec292664239df5279c1
  SVPullToRefresh: ba2e718695a43253d8bea6852d2960097dc15d8c
  SWTableViewCell: 2a94aadc9d47b2b611fa064566bf57948b95b579
  TapkuLibrary: 7a406dac46eff8595e191557eba88959f97f69b7
  TSAssetsPickerController: c5ff3e518cc51605b1d925182f1e8f0b1edf8c89
  UICountingLabel: 1db4e7d023e1762171eb226d6dff47a7a84f27aa
  UIImage-ResizeMagick: f08c2d14d1e8a5f0b402185408785540562f2fe7
  UIScrollSlidingPages: d75e0f718993ef0481a6adf8251bfc52cabeb3ff
  VTAcknowledgementsViewController: 575f5841fb47b7d9c852ccb406104ea68de07b21
  WCFastCell: 3e20a0c711d27307584bdbd359a44a714e991151

COCOAPODS: 0.39.0.beta.4
```

Any idea or extra info I could give?

Thanks.

**Edit**: I have finally downgraded all the pods using swift to the objective c version and  I've generated the workspace with Cocoapods v0.35.0. Now it's working.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced similar issue after upgrading cocoapods/using `use_frameworks!` and it wouldn't work for one of the build targets.

The difference between the two was the second target was missing  Embed Pods Frameworks script in Target > Build Phases.

Comment: I finally worked around this downgrading CocoaPods and removing Swift Pods.